C# .NET MAUI - Android TabGestureRecognizer open multiple pages
The bug is that if I double click on the frame, two instances of the page will open.
MAUI - latest
VS - latest
.NET - 8
<Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" Padding="0,10,0,10" IsVisible="{Binding Okruh1_active}">
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                     NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                     Tapped="CircleOneSliderPage_Tapped" />
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                                <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                    <Image
                                     Source="house_circle.png"
                                     Aspect="AspectFit"
                                     MaximumHeightRequest="40"
                                     MaximumWidthRequest="40"
                                     Margin="5"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center" />

                                    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label
                                         Text="{x:Static strings:AppResources.UniCircle1}"
                                         FontAutoScalingEnabled="True"
                                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                                         HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                         HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />

                                        <Label
                                         Text="{Binding Write_t05, StringFormat='{0} °C'}"
                                         FontSize="Small"
                                         TextColor="{StaticResource GrayUniversal}"
                                         FontAutoScalingEnabled="True"
                                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                                         HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
                                    </VerticalStackLayout>

                                    <Label
                                      Text="{x:Static strings:AppResources.UniSetText}"
                                      TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource GrayUniversal}, Dark={StaticResource Gray300}}"
                                      FontAutoScalingEnabled="True"
                                      HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                                      Margin="10" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>


Here is .cs method
    private async void CircleOneSliderPage_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CircleOneSliderPage());
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // check fail
            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
            // break point place
        }
    }

How to do would open only one instance of the page not more.
On iOS, everything works fine, but on Android, more pages fly out.

To resolve the issue you can implement a mechanism to prevent multiple rapid taps from triggering the navigation action

Disable the gesture recognizer after the first tap.
Re-enable it after the navigation completes.

    private bool _isNavigating = false;

    private async void CircleOneSliderPage_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        
    if (_isNavigating) return;
    
        _isNavigating = true;
    
        try
        {
            await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CircleOneSliderPage());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
        finally
        {
            _isNavigating = false;
        }
    }

  

